# html.js loading the script only once on page load Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, ghost-blog

I am using html.js to load custom script. I have created a js file in static folder `custom.js` but when I am running my project it loads the script only once on first time page load but when I am navigation to other page it not loading the script.

My `custom.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("in ready");
});
```

My `html.js` file

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withPrefix } from "gatsby";

export default function HTML(props) {
    return (
        <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
            <head>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
                <meta
                    name="viewport"
                    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
                />
                <script
                    type="text/javascript"
                    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"
                ></script>
                <link
                    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.css"
                    rel="stylesheet"
                    type="text/css"
                />
                {props.headComponents}
            </head>
            <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
                {props.preBodyComponents}
                <div
                    key={`body`}
                    id="___gatsby"
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
                />
                {props.postBodyComponents}
                <link
                    rel="stylesheet"
                    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                />
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script
                    type="text/javascript"
                    src={withPrefix("js/custom.js")}
                ></script>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}

HTML.propTypes = {
    htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
    headComponents: PropTypes.array,
    bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
    preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
    body: PropTypes.string,
    postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
};
```

What I am doing here wrong ? Why it's loading script only once ? What I have to do load `custom.js` script on every page navigation?

I have also tried to include `custom.js` inside my Layout file in `<Helmet></Helmet>` but same issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am doing here wrong ? Why it's loading script only once ? What
> I have to do load custom.js script on every page navigation?

I think that there is a misunderstanding and a mix of context on how React and old-fashioned scripting like jQuery works. In the end, Gatsby is a React-based application.

Among saying that Reacts manipulates a [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html) (vDOM) and jQuery points directly to the DOM, which has an extremely high-cost impact on performance. If you mix both approaches outside the scope of React, you can block [React's hydration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/), potentially breaking your application.

You can simply create a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook with empty dependencies (`[]`), which will be triggered once the DOM tree is loaded for each page it's included. React's lifecycle should work for your use-case without overkilling the customization of the HTML generated by Gatsby.

Your `custom.js` file must have something exported. As simply as:

```
const customJS =()=> console.log("I'm ready");

export default customJS;
```

Then, on any page:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import customJS from "../path/to/custom.js";

const AnyPage =(props)=>{

   useEffect(()=>{
     customJS()
   }, [])


return <div>Some content for AnyPage()<div>
}
export default AnyPage;
```

`customJS()` will be triggered only one time per page, once the DOM is loaded.

Please, don't use jQuery along with React, it's not needed.